# JQuery calling bind() logic twice, only on reload

Tags: jquery, click, bind

I have the folllowing code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#Titles .item a").each(function (index, domEle) {
        // 1)
      $(this).ttip($.extend(true, {}, ttip_opts, {
                content: {
                    text: $(this).attr('title'),
                    title: {
                        text: "SomeText"
                    }
                }
            }));
       // 2)
            $(this)
                .bind("click", function (event) {
                    alert(this);
                })
                .attr('title', '');
        });
});
```

When I click ‘reload’ on the page, and click the link, the alert statement shows up twice.  On subsequent clicks, it appears once.

When I comment out statement #1, it only appears once every time.

What is happening here?  How can I get the alert statement to display once every time?  There is only one anchor element in the element I'm looping through.

**Update**

I still get two clicks on my method (now called from another script) even when I remove the bind to the click event.  So the each function is definitely executing the logic in the click() method on reload only.

Still trying to figure out how I can determine if it's being called on reload, so I at least ignore the logic I don't want to run twice.

Comment: did you forget to put your "$(document).ready(function () {" closing tag?

Comment: Yes .. verified the closing tag is in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ttip` plugin is triggering the `click` event on the element which I think is not required. You can try this which stops the event propagation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#Titles .item a").each(function (index, domEle) {
            // 2)
            $(this)
                .bind("click", function (event) {
                    alert(this);
                    return false;
            }).attr('title', '');

        // 1)
        $(this).ttip($.extend(true, {}, ttip_opts, {
                content: {
                    text: $(this).attr('title'),
                    title: {
                        text: "SomeText"
                    }
                }
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: That suggestion did not quite work.  Changing the order around results in an invalid object reference for ttip.